# ItemRenderer display image according variable

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I have the following code from an InterRenderer, where I try to display two kind of icons depending on the value of its labelField within a Datagrid.

```
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;
        import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;

        import spark.components.DataGrid;

        private var _listData:BaseListData;
        [Bindable]
        private var _isSelected:Boolean;

        override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {}

        override public function set data( value:Object ) : void  {
            super.data  = value;
            //Alert.show( value.sent );
            _isSelected = data.sent=='1'?true:false;

        }

        [Bindable]public function get listData() : BaseListData {
            return _listData;
        }
        public function set listData( value:BaseListData ) : void {
            _listData = value;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Image id="btn_ok" horizontalCenter="0" source="@Embed('assets/images/ok_icon.png')"
         visible="{_isSelected?true:false}"
         verticalCenter="0"/>

<s:Image id="btn_ko" horizontalCenter="0" source="@Embed('assets/images/send_icon.png')"
         visible="{_isSelected?false:true}"
         verticalCenter="0"/>
```

The question is that I need to link the value of the labelField and in case it changes, one image hides and the other shows.

What's wrong in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: My gut impulse is that your conditional in the "visible" property binding is going to cause issues.  Why not just set the visible property on each Image in the set data function?

Comment: Tryed and it does not work. I think the issue is that data.sent arise an error (is not shown, but the screen do not show)

Comment: Did you try to run your code in debug mode?